# Is there a way to add 2 or more switch statements together

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I have been researching and looking up different forms for hours now and cant seem to find a way to add multiple switch statements together. I have shortened the switch's to make it easier to post.

I taught I could just do the adding after the last switch but doesn't seem to work as the app crashes with no error.

```
TextView tvanwser;
int total,ttband1,ttband2,ttband3;
```

```
 {
 radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId)
                {
                    case R.id.rbBlack1:
                        band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                        ttband1 = 0;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbBrown1:
                        band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
                        ttband1 = 1;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbOrange1:
                        band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                        ttband1 = 3;
                        break;
               }
              });

 radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId)
                {
                    case R.id.rbBlack2:
                        band2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                         ttband2 = 2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbBrown2:
                        band2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
                          ttband2 = 3;
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbOrange2:
                        band2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                        ttband2 = 4;
                        break;
}
});


total = ttband1 + ttband2;
tvAnswer.setText(total);

}
```

Comment: `the app crashes with no error.` this doesn't sound correct, have you had a look at your logs

Comment: I don't think your switch cases were the problem to crash your app.

Comment: You need to explain what you *mean* by "adding together".

Comment: I have 3 RadioGroups with 5 radio buttons in each. so when u click on 1 button from each group it adds them all together and outputs an answer @HasinduDahanayake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know what you are trying to achieve and don't think that your crashes are related to your code. But i can tell that your line

```
total = ttband1 + ttband2;
```

will not work as you intend.
Adding a listener (setOnCheckedChangeListener) on an element will register a function that executes as soon as the condition for the listener is reached. In this case: as soon as the radiogroup is checked or unchecked.

This means that the values for ttband1 and ttband2 are only changed while you interact with the UI elements.

```
total = ttband1 + ttband2;
tvAnswer.setText(total);
```

Your last two lines of code however will execute immediately after your listeners are added. At this point your values ttband1 and ttband2 were not modified and are probably 0.

To stay up-to-date everytime your values ttband1 or ttband2 are changed you need to move the lines into your listener functions.

```
 radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch (checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.rbBlack1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                    ttband1 = 0;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbBrown1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
                    ttband1 = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbOrange1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                    ttband1 = 3;
                    break;
           }

           total = ttband1 + ttband2;
           tvAnswer.setText(total);
          });
```

Comment: The problem i have is that each radio button does 2 tasked. 1. to change the color of a button and 2. to update the formula. the change of color works but not the updating of the formula.  i added the total into each switch and it still crashes

Comment: @kyle please provide an error message. From your posted code only we can't really tell why it crashes. The issue is probably related to some other issue.

Comment: Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:402)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6942)
        at edu.kylegilmartin.ass1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:193)

Comment: @kyle Check your line 193 in MainActivity.java
You have probably not defined the TextView correctly

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: edu.kylegilmartin.ass1, PID: 5619
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
       at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:402)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6942)
        at edu.kylegilmartin.ass1.MainActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(MainActivity.java:111)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:200)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:63)
        at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:385)

Answer (score 1):

I never converted the int to a string witch caused the app to crash

```
   total = total1 + total2 + total3;
   tvanwser.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

```
 radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch (checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.rbBlack1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                    ttband1 = 0;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbBrown1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
                    ttband1 = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbOrange1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                    ttband1 = 3;
                    break;
           }

                total1 = ttband1;
                total = total1 + total2 + total3;
                tvanwser.setText(String.valueOf(total));
          });




 radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

            switch (checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.rbBlack1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBlack));
                    ttband2 = 0;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbBrown1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorBrown));
                    ttband2 = 1;
                    break;
                case R.id.rbOrange1:
                    band1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOrange));
                    ttband2 = 3;
                    break;
           }

                total2 = ttband2;
                total = total1 + total2 + total3;
                tvanwser.setText(String.valueOf(total));
          });
```